# When has the Tory party split over trade issues?

Tags: united-kingdom, trade

Today in a leaked UK Government memo it says the UK Tory Party has split 4 times in last 200 years over global trade.  When were these 4 splits and over what?

Here is the [Reuters link to the memo](http://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-eu-memo-text-idUKKBN13A0UO) itself.

I can definitely think of one split over trade, the Corn Laws.  I was wondering what the other 3 were.  I suppose today's Tory party is split over the EU so that must be a second.  Anyone else got the other two?

Answer (score 2):

One case in point is the [Tariff Reform League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tariff_Reform_League) of Joe Chamberlain:

> Tariff Reform split the MPs of the Conservative Party and their
>   government coalition allies in the Liberal Unionist Party and was the
>   major factor in its landslide defeat in 1906 to the Liberals who
>   advocated Free Trade.